# Форматирование конфигурационных файлов Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Настройки многих конфигурационных файлов Sublime Text 3, например, с расширениями `.sublime-settings`, `.sublime-keymap` или `.sublime-theme` хранятся в формате JSON. [Не только я](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247473/#comment_8213839) считаю, что он менее удобен в сравнении с [Hjson](https://hjson.org/) или YAML, в частности, потому что если в файле находятся комментарии или запятая в конце массива, он [становится невалидным](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/RK8qyGVaGSr).

Например, я внёс изменения в файл моей темы с поддерживаемыми Sublime Text 3 комментариями и запятыми, который выглядит не очень красиво:

```
[
    //Полосы прокрутки
{"class": "scroll_bar_control",
"layer0.tint": [0, 250, 154]
    },
// Вертикальный бегунок, требуется добавить файлы, см. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31094548/5951529
        {"class": "puck_control","layer0.texture": "User/Theme - SashaSublime/vertical_white_scrollbar.png",
"layer0.tint": [200, 170, 250],
"layer0.opacity": 1.0, "layer0.inner_margin": [0, 10], "content_margin": [8, 12],
                "blur": false,
    },]
```

Комментарии мне нужны, удалять их не хочу. Есть ли beautifier, приводящий в порядок индентацию конфигурационных файлов Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Не поможет

#### Форматтеры для валидных JSON

**Онлайн**

Вроде [JSON Editor online](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) или [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Покажут, что JSON невалиден, и не станут форматировать.

**Плагины для Sublime Text**

[Pretty JSON](https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson) и [Indent XML](https://github.com/alek-sys/sublimetext_indentxml) (beautifier для JSON и XML) также не форматируют невалидные файлы. [JSON Reindent](https://github.com/ThomasKliszowski/json_reindent) у меня не работает корректно, в консоль выдаются ошибки.

#### Прочие инструменты

[Jsonnet](http://jsonnet.org/) удаляет комментарии.

#### Замена комментариев на параметр "comment"

[Пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244858/5951529), что можно заменить комментарий `// Саша непостижима` на что-то вроде `{"comment": "Саша непостижима"}`, неважно, внутри массива (без {фигурных скобок}, `"comment": "Саша непостижима"`) или перед ними. Это можно сделать регулярными выражениями. Пример:

**Поиск**: `\/\/ (.*)\n( {4}){`
**Замена**: `{   "comment": "$1",`
**Демонстрация**: https://regex101.com/r/fD9hW0/1

Или автоматически, при помощи [comment-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/comment-json).

Конфигурация сохраняется, JSON становится валидным, и его можно форматировать способами выше. Вроде бы проблема разрешена, однако в консоли (<kbd>Ctrl+'</kbd> (машинописный обратный апостроф, символ расположен на той же клавише, где кириллическая «ё»)) будет постоянно выдавать `no such prop comment`.

[image: No such prop comment]

Замена `comment` на любое другое слово не решит проблему консоли. Не знаю, как это сказывается на функциональности Sublime Text 3, однако, понятно, что пользоваться консолью, где то и дело выскакивают ошибки, не очень комфортно.

### Поможет

JSON — составляющая [ECMAScript](https://github.com/ThomasKliszowski/json_reindent), и отформатировать файлы с синтаксисом JSON можно при помощи лучшего по вашему мнению prettifier для JavaScript. Для Sublime Text на Stack Overflow [рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21206739/5951529) воспользоваться плагином [HTML/CSS/JS Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify).

После установки HTML/CSS/JS Prettify не будет форматировать по умолчанию конфигурационные файлы Sublime Text 3, требуется его настройка, отличающаяся от настройки остальных плагинов. `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `HTML/CSS/JS Prettify` → `Set Prettify Preferences` → копируем полностью содержимое открывшегося файла (если в новый файл скопировать только отдельные строки, значения в которых изменим на требуемые, плагин не заработает корректно). `Preferences` → `Browse Packages` → `User` → в открывшейся папке создаём файл `.jsbeautifyrc` → вставляем скопированное, меняем

```
"allowed_file_extensions": ["js", "json", "jshintrc", "jsbeautifyrc"],
```

на

```
"allowed_file_extensions": ["js", "json", "jshintrc", "jsbeautifyrc", "sublime-keymap", "sublime-theme", "sublime-settings"],
```

Если потребуется, аналогично вставляем другие расширения → сохраняем файл. Файл `.jsbeautifyrc` [можно поместить](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify#using-your-own-jsbeautifyrc-options) в другие папки, но если создадите его именно в `User`, HTML/CSS/JS Prettify будет работать с файлами необходимых расширений, где бы они не находились. Создавать пользовательский файл `.jsbeautifyrc` необходимо, поскольку если редактировать дефолтный, то при обновлениях плагина сбросятся все кастомные настройки.

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `HTMLPrettify` → JSON из вопроса плагин отформатирует следующим образом:

```
[
    //Полосы прокрутки
    {
        "class": "scroll_bar_control",
        "layer0.tint": [0, 250, 154]
    },
    // Вертикальный бегунок, требуется добавить файлы, см. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094548/5951529
    {
        "class": "puck_control",
        "layer0.texture": "User/Theme - SashaSublime/vertical_white_scrollbar.png",
        "layer0.tint": [200, 170, 250],
        "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
        "layer0.inner_margin": [0, 10],
        "content_margin": [8, 12],
        "blur": false,
    },
]
```

### Плагины для работы с конфигурационными файлами Sublime Text

#### Preferences Editor

Позволяет редактировать `.sublime-settings` файлы не вручную, а через Quick Panel плагина; файл настроек будет в отформатированном виде. Положим, мы хотим, чтобы бинарные файлы открывались бы при помощи плагина [Hex Viewer](https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer). Устанавливаем [Preferences Editor](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Preferences%20Edito) через Package Control → <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Edit Preferences: Edit Settings...` → `hex_viewer` → `auto_open`

[image: Auto open]

→ `true`. Внизу появляется панель, где приводятся комментарии к выбранному параметру, если разработчики их привели.

[image: Комментарии]

Проверяем: `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `Hex Viewer` → `Settings - User` → файл будет таким.

```
{
    "auto_open": true
}
```

Настройки записываются в пользовательский файл, так что при обновлениях плагина они не собьются.

Пробуем открыть бинарный файл → плагин Hex Viewer должен задействоваться автоматически.

С их помощью можно упростить редактирование `.sublime-settings` файлов, но только их. Готовых плагинов для автоматической правки других конфигурационных файлов я не нашёл.

#### Preference Helper

Плагин позволяет быстро переходить к `.sublime-settings` файлам, которые, правда, придётся редактировать вручную. Устанавливаем [плагин](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Preference%20Helper) → `Preference Helper: Open *.sublime-settings` → вводим имя плагина/синтаксиса/встроенного средства, настройки которого хотим изменить → откроется файл настроек.

[image: Preference Helper]

Пользоваться Preferences Editor мне выходит поудобнее.