# Как в Sublime Text 3 установить вертикальную линию на 80 символе

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

В Geany например она есть
[image: Линия на 80 символе]

Как сделать ее в Sublime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выберите

> View -> Ruler -> 80

Можно сделать еще так, чтобы текст сам переносился после 80 символов:

> View -> Word Wrap Column -> 80 (должна быть выставлена опция View -> Word Wrap)

Так же можно задать все выше перечисленное в конфигурационном файле, к которому можно "достучаться" по следующему пути:

> Preferences -> Settings - User

Установив у ключа `"rulers"` значение в массиве (в вашем случае 80):

```
"rulers": [80],
```

Если вы хотите отобразить две линии, перечислети значения в массиве:

```
"rulers": [80, 120],
```

Кроме того, в этом же файле пользовательских настроек можно установить: автоперенос слов и его параметры, шрифт, размер шрифта и многое другое =) Более подробно о форматировании конфигурационных файлов *Sublime Text* смотрите в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566060/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-sublime-text-3?rq=1).